# Boolean operation on two separate tensors to identify images misclassified in MNIST using Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, mnist

Using Pytorch to evaluate a Convolutional Neural Network model for MNIST, I am trying to identify and inspect the misclassified images in my test set.  I would like to see why the model had trouble predicting the accurate label.

From my confusion matrix, I can see that my model had trouble in differentiating between 2s and 7s, and 4s and 9s:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPuOB.png)

My test predictions are in a tensor called *test_predictions*, and the actual labels of the test set are in a tensor called *test_labels*.

I found some code I could use to see the indices of when my test prediction did not match my test label:

**comparison_result = torch.where(test_predictions != test_labels)[0].unique()**

This created a tensor with the list of indices when things didn't match.

I then tried evolving it to a specific case when the test prediction was a "2" but the test label was a "7."

I first tried identifying the indices of when the test_prediction was a "2"

**comparison_resultTWO = torch.where(test_predictions == 2)[0].unique()**

This produced a tensor with the indices of when the test prediction was a "2"

I thought I could do something like this, but got an error:

**
comparison_resultTWO = torch.where((test_predictions == 2) and (test_label == 7))[0].unique()**

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[200], line 1
----> 1 comparison_resultTWO = torch.where((test_predictions == 2) and (test_label == 7))[0].unique()

RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous**

Is there a way to use some kind of boolean operation (i.e., AND) to identify the index of the test set for misclassified images?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as no answers yet, I just point to code that do the work, althow, not the subj way.
https://www.kaggle.com/code/leshabirukov/mnist-pytorch-1
In two words: task you try to do, is not for NN body, it is post processing related thing, then you not 'look inside' tensors, rather 'poke it with stick from outside'.